# SVG importer does not import SVG at the same size

Tags: unity-game-engine, svg, unity3d-2dtools

I'm using the SVG importer from unity3d:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.vectorgraphics@2.0/manual/index.html

I have a sample svg i'm using as a ship:
[image]

I also created a sample turret in inkscape:
[image]

As you can see on `layer 1` i copied part of the sample ship as reference, and created the turret sample sprite. I then import the resulting SVG (with `layer 1` invisible ofcourse) and heres the result:

[image]

I've placed the sample turret next to the ship for reference, and as you can see the turret is **extremely small**. I do not understand the difference - since the importer has the same settings, i'd think they would come out the same size.

For reference, here are the top parts (posting it all is too much data i'd think) of the resulting svg:

sample_ship.svg

```
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="941.16632"
   height="748.34143"
   id="svg2"
   version="1.1"
   inkscape:version="0.92.4 (5da689c313, 2019-01-14)"
   inkscape:export-filename="/Users/administrator/Documents/Documents/Mark/Spaceshipblue2.png"
   inkscape:export-xdpi="72"
   inkscape:export-ydpi="72"
   sodipodi:docname="sample_spaceShip.svg">
```

sample_turret.svg

```
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="210mm"
   height="297mm"
   viewBox="0 0 210 297"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg1032"
   inkscape:version="0.92.4 (5da689c313, 2019-01-14)"
   sodipodi:docname="sample_turret.svg">
```

Also let me know if the `svg` tag is appropriate or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SVGs have not been exported with the same settings.

- Your ship file specifies `width` and `height` in pixels, and has no `viewBox`.
- Your turret file specifies `width` and `height` in millimetres, and also has a `viewBox`.

The step "I copied part of the ship to a new file" was probably where it went wrong.

1. Try adding the turret to your ship file. But give it it's own layer.
2. Hide the turret layer before you export the ship file.
3. Then hide the ship layer(s) before exporting the turret file.

You should then have compatable SVG files.

Comment: hello, thanks for your time. Yes indeed. I set the document size of both svg files to 1920x1080 px. I then (by editing the svg file directly, because i could find no inkscape option) removed the `viewbox`. Now the sizes are appropriate. Unfortunately - they still do not look nice in unity3d so i think i may have to do some more reading.. Thanks for your help!